# Use JS to trigger a delegated event

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with a number of grids all with the same class = "notegrid". Within each such grid there is a varying number of inputs, which can be range, text, or number.

I have added an event listener named extractUserInput(event) to each notegrid's click event:

```
let allNoteGrids = document.querySelectorAll("div.notegrid");
    for (let i = 0; i < allNoteGrids.length; i++){
        allNoteGrids[i].addEventListener("click", extractUserInput);
        allNoteGrids[i].addEventListener("blur", extractUserInput);
        allNoteGrids[i].addEventListener("change", extractUserInput);
        allNoteGrids[i].setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
        // For mobile functionality
        allNoteGrids[i].addEventListener("touchend", extractUserInput);
    }
```

When a user clicks on any of the inputs this function determines which actual element raised the click event:

```
function extractUserInput(event){
    
    // Local variables which track which input was used and what type it was
    let slider = event.target.closest("input[type='range']");
    let numeric = event.target.closest("input[type='number']");
    let text = event.target.closest("input[type='text']");
```

The function then carries out whatever is meant to happen on the specific element which was clicked.
Now, all this works perfectly BUT I wish to fire a click event for a specific input. How is this done? I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("details").click();
```

where the grid in question has id="details" but nothing happens. This is because since no input element was clicked, there is no event from which to find event.target.closest.
Similarly with:

```
document.getElementById("tasting").click();
```

where the actual input has id="tasting".

So, as far as I can tell there is no way to fire a delegated event as I cannot see how to pass the event as a parameter.

So, following on from comments here below, I tried this:

```
document.getElementById("tasting").value = 1;
document.getElementById("details").dispatchEvent("click");
```

The first line changes a slider value, the second should then fire the delegated event in the notegrid element with id="details". If this worked I would see various changes on the page as carried out by extractUserInput() BUT I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event';

Similarly with:

```
document.getElementById("tasting").value = 1;
document.getElementById("tasting").dispatchEvent("click");
```

Then, copying from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events I tried this:

```
document.getElementById("tasting").value = 1;
    
    function simulateClick() {
            const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true})
    };
    
    const s = document.getElementById('details');
    s.dispatchEvent(event);
```

which results in this error:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.

This error also arises if I try id="tasting".

I used a delagated event listener because of comments in response to other posts, and I can see why they are useful - fewer eventlisteners should mean quicker execution and so forth, and when any input is clicked or changed the page responds perfectly.
However, it seems there is no way to force an input event unless the actual input element has an event listener added to it specifically.

While I appreciate the ideas suggested, they do nothing.

Do I need to write a specific function for the situations where I want this to happen, or is there a way to achieve this?

All the best,

Dermot

Answer (score 0):

You could try to trigger the event with

```
extractUserInput({target:document.getElementById("tasting"),type:"click"})
```

This will call your universal event handler with a "fake" event object as parameter. It should get you the expected result.

You could even create a wrapper function to make it easier for a general case:

```
function extractFromId(id){
  extractUserInput({target:document.getElementById(id),type:"click"})
}
```

Now you can trigger a `click` event by simply calling `extractFromId("details")` or `extractFromId("tasting")`.

**Since OP did not provide an MCVE I made one myself:**
Here is a working snippet with *my* version of `extractUserInput()`. When calling it from within the button event handler, I added the `type` property into the "fake" event object. You can now trigger some of the events programmatically by clicking on one of the buttons below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".notegrid").forEach(el=>
 "click,blur,change,touchend,input".split(",").forEach(ty=>
   el.addEventListener(ty,extractUserInput)
 )
);
function extractUserInput(event){
let ty=event.type;
// Local variables which track which input was used and what type it was
let slider = event.target.closest("input[type='range']");
let numeric = event.target.closest("input[type='number']");
let text = event.target.closest("input[type='text']");
console.log(numeric?`the number ${numeric.id} was ${ty}-ed: ${numeric.value}`:
            text?   `the text ${text.id} was ${ty}-ed: ${text.value}`:
            slider? `the slider ${slider.id} value was ${ty}-ed: ${slider.value}`:
            "unknown input");
}

// attach button events for programmatic event triggering:
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(b=>{
  let [type,_,id]=b.textContent.split(" "); 
  id=id.replaceAll('"',"");
  b.onclick=ev=>{
   // now: trigger the type event manually on the target id:
   extractUserInput({target:document.getElementById(id),type:type});
  }
})
```

```html
<h2>Table</h2>
<table><thead><tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr></thead>
<tbody class="notegrid">
<tr><td><input type="text" id="name" value="John"> name</td><td><input type="number" id="qty" value="3"> qty</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" id="tasting" value="wine"> tasting</td><td><input type="number" id="details" value="27"> details</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" id="venue" value="restaurant"> venue</td><td><input type="number" id="table" value="12"> table</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<h2>Divs</h2>
<div class="notegrid">
 <input type="text" id="town" value="Hanover"> town<br>
 <input type="number" id="size" value="500000"> size
</div>
<div class="something else">
 <input type="text" id="region" value="Lower Saxony - no event handling here!" size="40"> region
</div>
<br>
<button>click on "tasting"</button>
<button>input on "details"</button>
<button>change on "size"</button>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, absolutely nothing happens - no errors, nothing.

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what else your `extractUserInput()` function does. It might rely on further properties of the `event` argument that is passed in. Maybe you can track by means of some console.log statements which parts of your function are actually executed?

Comment: I know that the function is not executed in any way by trying to call it - it only works if a user clicks an input but it does not seem possible to call it programatically.

Comment: It is difficult to say more without having an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added "my own" MCVE. Maybe it helps to demonstrate my point?

Comment: Again, nothing happens using your suggestion extractUserInput({target:document.getElementById("tasting"),type:"click"})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247097/discussion-between-carsten-massmann-and-dermotmw).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually *dispatch* a custom *event* by using the [`.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) method. It requires you to pass an event object, that you can create with the appropriate [event constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#interfaces_based_on_event).

To simulate a click event, uou can do the following:

```
const e = new MouseEvent('click', {
  //Object defining the behavior and properties of the event
  //e.g. bubbles: true/false, cancelable: true/false, etc.
});

document.getElementById("tasting").dispatchEvent(e);
```

You can read more about this [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) or [on javascript.info](https://javascript.info/dispatch-events).

Comment: This just generates an error: Identifier 'event' has already been declared

Comment: @DermotMW If you do it on the global scope, it does so because `window.event` is a thing and I happened to name my variable `event`. If you use any other name for the variable (I just renamed it), it should work.